# add background color in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to add background color to column in alternatively.I have list of item which is generated in dynamically.views-row-1,views-row-2,views-row-3, etc.inside it has contactTitle and contactDesc.

If I click the ContactTitle of views-rows-2 I want to show contactDesc of 2nd views and hide other views contactDesc and vice versa. Its working fine.

I want to add color in alternate cell If I select 'title 1'It wants to be in purple and 'desc 1' want to be in gray color and 'title 2' is in purple color and 'title 3' is in gray color.

If I click the 'title 2', 'title 1' is in purple  'title 2' in gray and 'desc 2' in gray and 'title 3' in purple. I want to show purple and gray color alternatively based on title clicked.

If title 1 is clicked desc 1 is visible
  title 1 -purple,desc 1 -gray,title 2 -purple,title 3 -gray
If title 2 is clicked only desc 2 is visible
  title 1 -purple,title 2 -gray,desc 2 - purple,title 3 -gray
If title 3 is clicked only desc 3 is visible
  title 1 -purple,title 2 -gray,title 3 -gray,desc 3-purple

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.views-row-1 .contactDesc').css('display','block');
 $('.views-row-1 .contactTitle').addClass('active');
  $('.contactTitle').click(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
      $('.contactDesc').slideUp();
      $('.contactTitle').removeClass('active');
      $(this).next('.contactDesc').slideDown();
      $(this).addClass('active');
    } 
  });
});
```

```css
.contactDesc{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
  <div class="contactTitle">
     Title 1
  </div> 
  <div class="contactDesc">
     desc 1
  </div> 
</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
  <div class="contactTitle">
     Title 2
  </div> 
  <div class="contactDesc">
     Desc 2
  </div> 
</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd">
  <div class="contactTitle">
     Title 3
  </div> 
  <div class="contactDesc">
     Desc 3
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove classes and apply to other elements alternatively on click.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.views-row-1 .contactDesc').css('display','block');
 $('.views-row-1 .contactTitle').addClass('active');
  
  $('.contactTitle').click(function(){ 
    
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
      $('.contactDesc').slideUp();
      $('.contactTitle').removeClass('active');
      $('.contactTitle').addClass('grey-bg');
      $(this).next('.contactDesc').slideDown(function(){
      $('.colorme').removeClass('grey').removeClass('purple');
          $('.colorme:visible:odd').addClass('purple');
          $('.colorme:visible:even').addClass('grey');
      });
      $(this).addClass('active');
    } 
  });
});
```

```css
.contactDesc{
  display:none;
}
.purple{
  background:purple;
}
.grey{
  background:grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
  <div class="contactTitle colorme">
     Title 1
  </div> 
  <div class="contactDesc colorme">
     desc 1
  </div> 
</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
  <div class="contactTitle colorme">
     Title 2
  </div> 
  <div class="contactDesc colorme">
     Desc 2
  </div> 
</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd">
  <div class="contactTitle colorme">
     Title 3
  </div> 
  <div class="contactDesc colorme">
     Desc 3
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: on load I want to set the color as given by u

Comment: Instead of setting up static open div you should use jquery trigger () for clicking title 2  dynamically